# For some reason wp_reset_postdata isn't working for me.

Tags: wordpress

Hoping someone can help me with this one - I've been able to debug a lot of code over the years with insight from this site.

I'm trying to run two wordpress queries on one page, but for some reason I can't clear out the data from the first query even after using wp_reset_postdata. What am I doing wrong? Should I be trying to query in some other way?

I also tried wp_reset_query, with no success.

This is in a custom theme - do I need something in functions.php to make this work? (I had to that once ages ago for post-thumbnails)

Here's the code:

```
            $args1 = array( 'category' => 'locations' );
            $myposts1 = get_posts( $args1 );
                foreach ( $myposts1 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

               <div class="post">

                     <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
                     <h2 class="post-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                     </h2>

                     <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
                     <p class="post-title-meta">
                        <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
                    </p>
                     <!-- Display the Post's Content in a div box. -->
                     <div class="post-entry">

                            <?php if ( ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') ) && ( has_post_thumbnail() ) ) { 
                                $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
                                ?>
                                <div class="post-image">
                                    <img title="image title" alt="thumb image" class="wp-post-image" src="<?php echo $post_thumbnail_url; ?>" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin-bottom:40px;">
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>


                        <?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?> 

                     </div><!-- post entry-->
                 </div> <!-- post -->  


                <?php endforeach; 
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

            </div> <!-- #col-md-5 --> 
            <!-- end of Locations -->


            <!-- second column-->
            <div class="col-md-5">

            <h2>Latest </h2>

             <?php


                $args2 = array( 'category' => 'secondcategory' );
                $myposts2 = get_posts( $args2 );
                    foreach ( $myposts2 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

                   <div class="post">

                         <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
                         <h2 class="post-title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                         </h2>

                         <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
                         <p class="post-title-meta">
                            <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
                        </p>
                         <!-- Display the Post's Content in a div box. -->
                         <div class="post-entry">

                                <?php if ( ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') ) && ( has_post_thumbnail() ) ) { 
                                    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                    $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="post-image">
                                        <img title="image title" alt="thumb image" class="wp-post-image" src="<?php echo $post_thumbnail_url; ?>" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin-bottom:40px;">
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>


                            <?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?> 

                         </div><!-- post entry-->
                     </div> <!-- post -->  



            <?php endforeach; 
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>


            </div> <!-- #col-md-5 -->  
           <!-- end of secondcatagory -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't clear out the data from the first query" ie what data are you seeing from the first query in the second loop?  And just to confirm - you don't have any posts with both categories?

Comment: Yeah - it's the same data showing in the second loop - and I've tested with categories that have none of the same posts.

Comment: I've found a fix for this by setting each column/loop  in functions.php. Not sure why this works but I'm not complaining.

Comment: Is it an admin page ?